# ASP.NET Core 3.1 slow publish to FTP

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, razor, publish

I have a new website project created in ASP.Net Core 3.1 with razor pages. The site contains a lot of content images and videos and every time I publish via FTP it takes about 5-10 minutes. This seems unacceptable to have the website down for that long to publish a spelling error change on a view. Am I missing something? Do I really need to republish the entire site every time?

Is there a way to at least exclude all static files and push them up only when needed?

Comment: You're free to script out your publish to happen however you want.

Comment: FTP is a 1980's technology. There are better alternatives today.

Comment: Any advice on where to begin learning about scripting out the publish? If FTP is not a good solution, any advice on what else to use? Thanks!